# Azure Custom Password Policy for Cloud Users

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am trying to set password policy only to cloud users in our tenant but did not get any option for that. Can anyone help me how to do?

Our tenant have AD sync Enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can [configure custom banned passwords for Azure AD password protection and account lockout parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/tutorial-configure-custom-password-protection).

Some of the Azure AD Password policies cannot be modified

As of now, there are three properties that can be configurable:

1. Password expiry duration
2. Password expiry notification
3. Password expiry

The Azure AD password policy doesn't apply to user accounts synchronized from an on-premises AD DS environment using Azure AD Connect, unless you enable EnforceCloudPasswordPolicyForPasswordSyncedUsers.

**Reference** :

[Self-service password reset policies - Azure Active Directory | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/concept-sspr-policy#password-policies-that-only-apply-to-cloud-user-accounts)

[Change Azure AD (AAD) password policy for cloud only accounts? (microsoft.com)](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/83f930e6-0e9d-4c6e-a1e4-0edba30f15d3/change-azure-ad-aad-password-policy-for-cloud-only-accounts)